# Gobby 0.4.12 install error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, glib, ubuntu-13.10

I ran across the following error when attempting to install Gobby 0.4.12 from source on Ubuntu 13.10.  Any ideas?
I'm fairly confident it's a version error, but I'm curious if anyone else has run across this same problem and found a fix.

```
src/gselector.cpp: In member function ‘void Gobby::GSelector::add_socket(const net6::socket&, net6::io_condition)’:
src/gselector.cpp:87:17: error: ‘signal_io’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
   sel.io_conn = Glib::signal_io().connect(
                 ^
src/gselector.cpp: In member function ‘void Gobby::GSelector::modify_socket(std::map<const net6::socket*, Gobby::GSelector::SelectedSocket>::iterator, net6::io_condition)’:
src/gselector.cpp:109:27: error: ‘signal_io’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
    iter->second.io_conn = Glib::signal_io().connect(
                           ^
src/gselector.cpp: In member function ‘void Gobby::GSelector::set_timeout(const net6::socket&, long unsigned int)’:
src/gselector.cpp:226:24: error: ‘signal_timeout’ is not a member of ‘Glib’
  sel_sock->time_conn = Glib::signal_timeout().connect(
```

Answer (score 1):

This A Known Bug And It Has Been Fixed In sobby - 0.4.8-1

Check Here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sobby/+bug/935447